# JSF/JPA/CDI: Problems when binding managed entities to a bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jsf-2, cdi

I am using a `@ConversationScoped CDI` to manage my form. Now, when loading a page, the entity is searched using `JPA`. I bind this entity directly onto my bean and accessing is like:

```
<h:inputText value=#{myForm.myEntity.name}/>
```

The problem is that it seems to be managed all the time, even if I do a

```
em.detach(myEntity);
myForm.myEntity = myEntity;
```

when binding the entity to my bean. Without a merge, the entity is updated in the underlying database.

What's going on there? Do I really need a deep copy of my object?

Is this probably an erroneous way to use `CDI` beans?

Comment: How do you do the binding of your entity ?

Comment: I have a primefaces <p:datatable> which holds a list of all users currently filtered. It also holds an array of currently selected users. The first element is assigned to the form bean after detaching, as shown above.